# How can one compute a 3D Periodic Delaunay Triangulation using DelaunayMesh?

Tags: version-10, computational-geometry

Given a non-periodic point set, one can easily tetrahedralize it using the new (in **V10**) `DelaunayMesh` function. e.g.:

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts3d = RandomReal[4, {200, 3}];
del = DelaunayMesh[pts3d];
style = MapThread[Style[#1, Directive[#2]] &, {{1, 0, 2}, {{Thin, Purple},
                         {PointSize[0.02], Red}, {Opacity[0.5], Green}}}];
HighlightMesh[del, style]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now consider the following periodic point set in 3D:

```
cavs = {{0., 1.199, 2.53}, {0., 1.265, 2.53}, {0.067, 1.199, 2.53}, {3.263, 
      1.199, 2.53}, {0.067, 1.265, 2.53}, {3.263, 1.265, 2.53}, {0.133, 
      1.199, 2.53}, {3.196, 1.199, 2.53}, {0.133, 1.265, 2.53}, {3.196, 
      1.265, 2.53}, {0.2, 1.199, 2.53}, {3.13, 1.199, 2.53}, {3.196, 
      1.199, 2.464}, {0.133, 1.265, 2.597}, {0.133, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.2, 
      1.265, 2.53}, {3.13, 1.265, 2.53}, {0.2, 1.199, 2.597}, {0.266, 
      1.199, 2.53}, {3.13, 1.199, 2.464}, {0.2, 1.265, 2.597}, {0.2, 
      1.332, 2.53}, {0.266, 1.265, 2.53}, {3.063, 1.265, 2.53}, {3.13, 
      1.265, 2.464}, {0.266, 1.132, 2.53}, {3.063, 1.199, 2.464}, {0.2, 
      1.265, 2.664}, {0.2, 1.332, 2.597}, {0.2, 1.398, 2.53}, {0.266, 
      1.332, 2.53}, {0.333, 1.265, 2.53}, {3.063, 1.265, 2.464}, {3.063, 
      1.332, 2.53}, {3.063, 1.199, 2.397}, {0.2, 1.398, 2.597}, {0.266, 
      1.332, 2.597}, {0.266, 1.398, 2.53}, {0.266, 1.332, 2.464}, {0.333, 
      1.332, 2.53}, {0.333, 1.265, 2.464}, {0.4, 1.265, 2.53}, {2.997, 
      1.265, 2.464}, {3.063, 1.265, 2.397}, {3.063, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.997,
       1.332, 2.53}, {2.997, 1.199, 2.397}, {3.063, 1.132, 2.397}, {3.063,
       1.199, 2.331}, {0.2, 1.465, 2.597}, {0.266, 1.398, 2.597}, {0.266, 
      1.332, 2.664}, {0.333, 1.332, 2.597}, {0.266, 1.465, 2.53}, {0.333, 
      1.398, 2.53}, {0.333, 1.332, 2.464}, {0.4, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.333, 
      1.199, 2.464}, {0.4, 1.265, 2.464}, {0.466, 1.265, 2.53}, {2.997, 
      1.265, 2.397}, {2.997, 1.332, 2.464}, {3.063, 1.265, 2.331}, {2.997,
       1.332, 2.597}, {2.997, 1.398, 2.53}, {2.997, 1.199, 2.331}, {0.266,
       1.465, 2.597}, {0.266, 1.398, 2.664}, {0.333, 1.398, 2.597}, {0.4, 
      1.398, 2.53}, {0.4, 1.332, 2.464}, {0.466, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.333, 
      1.132, 2.464}, {0.4, 1.199, 2.464}, {0.466, 1.265, 2.464}, {2.93, 
      1.265, 2.397}, {2.997, 1.332, 2.397}, {2.93, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.997, 
      1.398, 2.464}, {2.997, 1.398, 2.597}, {2.997, 1.132, 2.331}, {0.266,
       1.465, 2.664}, {0.333, 1.465, 2.597}, {0.333, 1.398, 
      2.664}, {0.466, 1.332, 2.464}, {0.533, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.333, 1.065, 
      2.464}, {0.466, 1.265, 2.397}, {2.93, 1.332, 2.397}, {2.997, 1.332, 
      2.331}, {2.863, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.93, 1.132, 2.331}, {0.266, 1.465, 
      2.73}, {0.533, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.863, 1.332, 2.397}, {2.997, 1.398, 
      2.331}, {2.863, 1.132, 2.331}, {0.266, 1.465, 2.797}, {0.333, 1.465,
       2.73}, {0.533, 1.332, 2.397}, {0.599, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.93, 1.398, 
      2.331}, {2.863, 1.199, 2.331}, {0.266, 1.465, 2.863}, {0.266, 1.532,
       2.797}, {0.599, 1.332, 2.397}, {0.666, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.797, 
      1.199, 2.331}, {0.266, 1.532, 2.863}, {0.333, 1.532, 2.797}, {0.666,
       1.332, 2.397}, {0.666, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.732, 1.332, 2.464}, {2.73, 
      1.199, 2.331}, {2.797, 1.265, 2.331}, {0.266, 1.598, 2.863}, {0.333,
       1.532, 2.863}, {0.666, 1.398, 2.397}, {0.732, 1.332, 
      2.397}, {0.732, 1.332, 2.53}, {0.732, 1.398, 2.464}, {0.799, 1.332, 
      2.464}, {2.664, 1.199, 2.331}, {2.73, 1.132, 2.331}, {2.73, 1.265, 
      2.331}, {0.333, 1.598, 2.863}, {0.732, 1.398, 2.397}, {0.799, 1.332,
       2.397}, {0.732, 1.332, 2.597}, {0.799, 1.398, 2.464}, {2.597, 
      1.199, 2.331}, {2.664, 1.199, 2.264}, {2.664, 1.199, 2.397}, {2.664,
       1.265, 2.331}, {2.73, 1.132, 2.264}, {2.73, 1.265, 2.397}, {0.799, 
      1.398, 2.397}, {0.799, 1.398, 2.53}, {0.799, 1.465, 2.464}, {0.866, 
      1.398, 2.464}, {2.597, 1.199, 2.397}, {2.664, 1.199, 2.197}, {2.664,
       1.265, 2.264}, {2.664, 1.265, 2.397}, {0.799, 1.398, 
      2.331}, {0.799, 1.465, 2.397}, {0.866, 1.398, 2.397}, {2.597, 1.132,
       2.397}, {2.597, 1.265, 2.397}, {2.664, 1.332, 2.264}, {0.799, 
      1.465, 2.331}, {0.866, 1.398, 2.331}}
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[cavs]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We tetrahedralize it naively:

```
cavdel = DelaunayMesh[cavs];
```

Visualize using the same `style` from before:

```
Show[HighlightMesh[cavdel, style], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Obviously, this is wrong as it's assuming the end of the box to be the end region and will lead to a larger volume than the true volume.

One can re-align the points in a box that gives them the minimum distance. When this is done the true arrangement of the points looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can then easily use `DelaunayMesh` to tetrahedralize and obtain the following:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the true Delaunay triangulation. The Delaunay tetrahedralization of the original periodic point set should look something like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, this is not quite right, since there are regions below and above the points that should fill up to the box edges and continue on the other side (wrap-around effect).

Since we can't give `DelaunayMesh` a `Distance` function AFAIK, my question is, given a set of periodic points in 3D how can one tetrahedralize it using `DelaunayMesh`?

**Note**: The length of the box is `3.2629` in each of `x`, `y` and `z` direction. Origin is `(0, 0, 0)` and Minimum image periodic boundary conditions were applied in all directions.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding what you are looking for, perhaps you could rephrase a bit?

Comment: @user21, Basically the distance between those points are not the normal `EuclideanDistance` so there is a wrap-around on points at the edge of the box.

Comment: Which dimensions are periodic ? all of them ?

Comment: @lalmei. Yes, all of them.

Comment: @Silvia. This is what I've done in the question, not just 6 directions but all 26 periodic boxes surrounding the center box. The problem with this approach is it's not feasible when you have 100's of such points in millions of configurations.

Comment: You can repeat your box in all directions, then tessellate the result.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't understand what you mean by "tessellate the result". You mean tessellate the result of all boxes with all points in those boxes?

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't read in full detail, hence the comment and no answer.  When I needed periodic Voronoi tessellation in the past, I did something like [this](http://ge.tt/7ZDKCxp1/v/0?c) (download link to notebook).

Comment: Was it of any use though, or did I get it totally wrong? :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, are you asking about the notebook in the link you posted?

Comment: Yes, about that.

Comment: @Szabolcs, your approach is interesting and works fine graphically, but you still have to find a way to select the box that contains the point set with minimum distances programmatically. Thanks for sharing though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main idea is to find the gap position dimension by dimension. Take the first dimension for example, to accomplish that, we first project the hold points set to x axis, and do some very basic but fast statistics to locate the "gap", then we shift the coordinates according to the it.

Here is an example:

```
(* Size of the periodic cell: *)
ℒ = 10;

(* example data: *)
cavs = RandomVariate[
                MultinormalDistribution[{3, 4, 5}, {{1, -(1/4), 1/3}, {-(1/4), 2/3, 1/5}, {1/3, 1/5, 1/2}}], 
                10^4] // 
            MapThread[#1@#2 &, {{Mod[#, ℒ, 4] &, Mod[#, ℒ, 2] &, Identity}, #}] &;

cavs // Graphics3D[{Blue, AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[#]}, 
            PlotRange -> 2 {{0, ℒ}, {0, ℒ}, {0, ℒ}}, Axes -> True, 
            AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, Bold, Italic] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}), 
            BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}] &
```

[image: original data]

```
AbsoluteTiming[
(* coords is the coordinates of the points in any one dimension: *)
    shiftParas = Module[{coords = #, crdSorted, threshold = 1, gapPos},
                    crdSorted = Sort[coords];
(* For sorted coords, gap position can be easily detected as a huge jump on a continuous distribution: *)
                    gapPos = 
                        Differences[crdSorted] // Sign[threshold - #] & // FirstPosition[#, -1] &;
                    If[#, {#, crdSorted[[Join[gapPos, gapPos + 1]]] // Mean}, {#, crdSorted[[{1, -1}]] // Mean}] &@ListQ[gapPos]
                    ] & /@ (cavs)
    ]
```

> ```
> {0.007005, {{True, 8.14929}, {True, 8.73281}, {False, 5.22408}}}
> ```

```
(* The rest work is just shift the points according to the shiftParas: *)
cavsShifted = 
        MapThread[
                If[#1[[1]], 
                        Mod[#2, ℒ, #1[[2]]] - #1[[2]],
                        #2 + ℒ/2 - #1[[2]]
                  ] &, {shiftParas, cavs}, 1];

cavsShifted // 
    Graphics3D[{Blue, AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[#]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{0, ℒ}, {0, ℒ}, {0, ℒ}}, Axes -> True, 
            AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, Bold, Italic] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}), 
            BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}] &
```

[image: shifted data]

For $10^6$ points it will take about 1 sec on my laptop.

Note for a more sophisticated statistics, functions like `HistogramList` should be used rather than simply `Differences`. The timing will be a bit more, but I think is bearable.

### Update:

For OP's example, we have:

[image: shifted data for OP]

Comment: @RunnyKine I believe it works, but please see my update and inform me my possible misunderstanding. (Have you set `ℒ` to your value i.e. `3.2629`?)

Comment: @RunnyKine You're welcome. Thanks for acceptance.